# Find homography knowing the "destination angles" and not locations of points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, homography

### What I'm doing

I'm trying to process (badly taken) photos of receipts and I'm stuck at warping perspective. My first attempt was to find the corners of the receipt using contour which worked pretty well.

But then I have images like this which part of the receipt was not captured (perhaps blocked by another piece of paper, etc.) so using the corners would yield bad result.

### What I tried

I then moved on to line detection using Hough transform. The idea is that receipts usually have a few horizontal lines across. This is what I have so far.

[image: know]

My first thought was to use `findHomography` using points on two sides as source. To calculate the `y`-coordinate of the destination points, I'd find the distance between that point and some reference line.

### The problem

But then I realized that this is not the correct way, as a line that's exactly halfway between top and bottom in the real receipt wouldn't be half way in the warped image.

### Question

So I don't know the locations of the "destination" points, but what I do know is that all these angles between the white and red lines should be 90 degrees. How do I find the transformation matrix in this case?

Comment: this is ambiguous. However, rotating the camera is done by K^-1 * R * K, where K is camera intrinsics and R is a rotation matrix (see Wikipedia). Not sure on which side of R the inversion of K is, but might find this elsewhere

Comment: Perhaps just find the top line and the bottom line (of text) and their end points where they intersect with the edges of the receipt. That gives 4 points. Use those with the width and height (between the lines) to do a perspective warp.

Comment: Search up "OpenCV four point perspective transform"

Comment: @nathancy The problem is I'm not sure which four points to use, since line detection could be unreliable (a crease in the paper, shadow, etc.) That's why I'd like to input all the points and let `findHomography` spit out outliers for me.